# WebOS versions supported by PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, webos

does anybody know which versions of **webOS** are supported by **PhoneGap** (Apache Cordova)?  Their [website](http://phonegap.com/about/features) does not provide specific information, they just list the device's features supported by the framework.

Thanks for your help and time.

Octavio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap/Cordova supports all versions of webOS, 1.0 through 3.0.5.  For tablet apps, you'll need to add a "uiRevision: 2" line to your appinfo.json file to use the full screen, and compass support is only on the Pre3 device.